# Forcing ext4lazyinit to finish its thing?

Tags: linux, ext4

Is there any way to 'force' `ext4lazyinit` to finish the thing it does with maximum priority? Something like "I don't care about my system's ressources, just do your job as fast as you can"?

I should add: Without reformatting the drive. I am aware of mkfs's lazy_itable_init option.

Comment: Sounds pretty [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: It took my Raspberry Pi multiple hours to finish ext4lazyinit on an external hard drive. I wanted to test if the hd spins down correctly after some time of inactivity however that wasn't possible due to ext4lazyinit. After looking at some kernel code (https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/ext4/super.c#L2931) it seems not possible to force the thread to finish since the delays are somewhat hardcoded. That is however no definitive answer, I am no kernel nor ext4 expert and I just took a glimpse at that function.

Comment: @Marius You are correct that the delay is hard-coded.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In order to 'force' ext4lazyinit to finish the thing it does with maximum priority, you need to mount the filesystem with 'init_itable=0'. By default it is 10 (for detail please see link below)

Alternative solution is to disable the ext4lazyinit thread by mount option '[noinit_itable](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ext4.5.html)' which may however not be a good idea on production system (for detail please see link below).

Source with detailed info here [ext4lazyinit git commit comment](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=bfff68738f1cb5c93dab1114634cea02aae9e7ba).

Comment: To get command that can be used to remount (without off lining) you can run `mount | grep /path/to/mount/point | sed -E 's/^.* on (.*) type ext4 \((.*)\)$/mount -o remount,init_itable=0,\2 \1/g'` - This will output something like `mount -o remount,init_itable=0,rw,noatime,seclabel,stripe=512,data=ordered /path/to/mount/point`

Comment: Thanks `init_itable=0` was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the 'nice' level of the process to a higher priority over others.  Not sure if it will make it go any faster though and could adversely affect system stability if set too high (-20 is the highest priority).

```
nice -n [nice value] [command]
```

Comment: nice would be giving it more CPU priority, what it needs is more IO priority, @VencaBSpam has the right solution

Comment: There is always ionice -c 2 (or possibly -c 1) for that (counterpart is ionice -c 3 for maximum "nice level").
However, neither of these are probably applicable to the lazy initialization, as there does not seen to be a pid associated to it.